# what do i need to fill the overcut parts of this electrical box?

Tags: drywall, repair, patching-drywall

[image: picture of electrical box hole]

This overcut box for honeywell thermostat is too wide for new ecobee. i don't want to use the trim plate, I'd rather fill and paint the overcut wings. Can I fix with just mesh tape and spackle? Or do I need to place small triangles of drywall?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: mesh tape and spackle will do

Comment: If anything, joint compound, not spackle. Spackle is for the hole left when you remove a nail from a photo frame. Can't help with what we can't see (or at least read about in detail), though.

Comment: picture added. face palmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ball up some mesh tape and shove it in the wings.

Then give it a good smoosh of mud (Joint compound) and smooth it out.

If you have no mesh tape some balled up paper or paper towel will work for such a small area.

Just don't make the balls too big or they will bulge past the edge of the drywall and cause you fits trying to make it all flat.